# Trouble training data with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Good day I'm working with Google colab training a model and when i try to run this block of code

```
history_1 = model_1.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=16, validation_data=(x_validate, y_validate))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bd00c937585f> in <module>()
----> 1 history_1 = model_1.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=16, validation_data=(x_validate, y_validate))

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_loss_and_target_compatibility(targets, loss_fns, output_shapes)
    683           raise ValueError('A target array with shape ' + str(y.shape) +
    684                            ' was passed for an output of shape ' + str(shape) +
--> 685                            ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '
    686                            'This loss expects targets to have the same shape '
    687                            'as the output.')

ValueError: A target array with shape (600, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 16) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my input im following an example from a TinyML book could someone help clarify how to resolve this issue?

Comment: you need to share the model

Answer (score 0):

Try a SparseCategoricalCrossentropy instead of CategoricalCrossentropy. It looks like your ground truth labels are sparse.